# How to hide Three20 TTTableViewController tableView while Loading

Tags: iphone, three20

How do you hide the tableView of TTTableViewController, while it's Loading?
It's kinda annoying to look at

Here is an example of what I mean..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and hide/show the table in the `TTModelDelegate` methods:

```
 #pragma mark TTModelDelegate

 - (void)modelDidStartLoad:(id<TTModel>)model { 
   [super modelDidStartLoad:model];

    < HIDE TABLE>
 }

 - (void)modelDidFinishLoad:(id<TTModel>)model {
     [super modelDidFinishLoad:model];

     < SHOW TABLE>
 }

 - (void)model:(id<TTModel>)model didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error {
     [super model:model didFailLoadWithError:error];

     < HIDE/SHOW (?) TABLE>
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Man, ill check your answer a little while since I can't still check it :)